# Global variables, shared libraries and -fPIC effect

Tags: c, dynamic-library, fpic

I made a piece of code which consists in a dynamic library (`lib.c`), and a main executable (`main.c`).
In both files I define a global variable named: `int global`.
Not very smart but it's not the question.

When I compile the dynamic library the `-fPIC` option seems mandatory:

```
gcc lib.c -fPIC -shared -o lib.so
```

otherwise I get:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccpUvIPj.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against '.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
```

When I compile the executable it is not.

```
gcc main.c -fPIC -ldl
gcc main.c -ldl
```

Both work, but have different behaviours I can not explain, could you ? :

with -fPIC, global in main.c and global in lib.c are the same variables:

```
global main: 23 (0x601050)
global lib: 23 (0x601050)
```

without -fPIC, global in lib.c is not correlated to global in main.c:

```
global main: 23 (0x601048)
global lib: 0 (0x7f7742e64028)
```

Here is the source :

lib.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int global;

int f_one() {

    printf("global lib: %d (%p)\n", global, &global);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

void * handle;
int global;

int main() {

    int q = 7;

    int (* f_one_p)(int a) = NULL;

    global = 23;

    handle = dlopen("./lib.so", RTLD_NOW);

    if (handle == 0) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    f_one_p = dlsym(handle, "f_one");

    printf("global main: %d (%p)\n", global, &global);

    f_one_p(q);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
```

gcc --version: gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.5.2-8ubuntu4) 4.5.2

uname -a: Linux xxx 2.6.38-11-generic #48-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 29 19:02:55 UTC 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

**edit**: code tested under SUN/sparc and x86/Linux architectures with the same kind of unexpected shared global variables (with -fPIC).

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7216244/168175

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you compile with `-fPIC` the object in question will determine the address of global symbols using the *Global Offset Table*. What happens though when part of the code is `-fPIC` and part isn't is that one of your `int global`s will be using this table to determine the address whilst the other part isn't.

If you had two shared object linked with `-fPIC`, but your main program not then you would still have two addresses for `int global`, one using the global offset table and one which was just local to the non-PIC code.

There's a [really great discussion on PIC vs pic vs non PIC](http://www.technovelty.org/code/c/amd64-pic.html) if you want to read further.

Answer (score 1):

By default, when building an executable references to variables are done internally, with a fixed offset and no relocation.

However, you're passing `-fPIC` and access to global data are converted to access via GOT and GOT relocations are added.