# Location of global variables w/o -fPIC

Tags: c, global-variables, fpic

Though some posts exist about the `-fPIC` effect (see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298186/global-variables-shared-libraries-and-fpic-effect) for example) most of them are unclear. I wrote an extremely simple example and I still can't figure out what happens w/o `-fPIC` regarding the location of global variables. Here is my C file:

```
$ cat main.c
#include <stdio.h>
int var1 = 94;
int var2 = 76;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int var1Loc = (int) &var1;
    int var2Loc = (int) &var2;
    printf("var1 address is: %d\n",var1Loc);
    printf("var2 address is: %d\n",var2Loc);
    printf("diff         is: %d\n",var2Loc-var1Loc);

    return var1+var2;
}
```

Then I compile it **with** `-fPIC` and run it twice:

```
$ gcc -Wno-pointer-to-int-cast -O0 -g -o main main.c
$ ./main
var1 address is: -2019672048
var2 address is: -2019672044
diff         is: 4
$ ./main
var1 address is: 1441697808
var2 address is: 1441697812
diff         is: 4
```

When I do the exact same thing **without** `-fPIC`
I get similar results. I thought that without the `-fPIC` the addresses
should be identical across runs no?

Comment: ASLR — Address Space Layout Randomization

Comment: I thought ASLR is only for the stack memory

Comment: OK — maybe it isn't ASLR.  Not that I've heard that ASLR only applies to stack memory — if you'd said "only shared library addresses" I'd be less surprised.  You'll have to wait for someone else with an alternative idea.  Sorry I can't help more.

Comment: Wikipedia on [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) — mentions _"ASLR randomly arranges the address space positions of key data areas of a process, including the base of the executable and the positions of the stack, heap and libraries."_

Comment: I used `echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space` to turn ASLR off and indeed the addresses are the same across runs. Either with or without `-fPIC`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an acronym (or [initialism](https://www.dailywritingtips.com/acronym-vs-initialism/)): ASLR — Address Space Layout Randomization.

Wikipedia on [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) says:

> ASLR randomly arranges the address space positions of key data areas of a process, including the base of the executable and the positions of the stack, heap and libraries.

This describes what you're seeing.  You subsequently found that using:

```
 echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space
```

to turn ASLR off meant that the addresses are the same across runs, either with or without `-fPIC`, thus confirming that ASLR was the cause of the address changes.

Note that your address printing should probably use the `%p` format and `void *` arguments (though you have a potentially truncating data conversion when you apply the `(int)` cast to the addresses — but the format is correct to use `%d`).  The type modifier `t` is for `ptrdiff_t`, the difference between two pointers.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int var1 = 94;
int var2 = 76;

int main(void)
{
    void *var1Loc = &var1;
    void *var2Loc = &var2;
    printf("var1 address is: %p\n", var1Loc);
    printf("var2 address is: %p\n", var2Loc);
    printf("diff         is: %td\n", &var2 - &var1);

    return 0;
}
```